# Каким членом предложения является инфинитив?

Tags: сказуемые, члены-предложения, дополнение

"Я забыл позвонить тебе вчера"
"Я научился кататься на коньках"
В данных случаях инфинитив является дополнением или частью составного глагольного сказуемого?

Answer (score 2):

Частью составного глагольного сказуемого.Вспомогательный глагол обозначает психическое переживание забыл и предрасположенность к действию научился, но не само действие, действие обозначает инфинитив.

Дополнением (объектным инфинитивом) было бы, если б инфинитив обозначал действие не подлежащего, а другого действующего лица: Я попросил его (о чём?) позвонить мне (я попросил, а звонить будет он). Я научил его кататься (Я научил его ( чему?) кататься)

Comment: Людмила, забыл позвонить СГС?

Comment: Да.    http://philolog.pspu.ru/module/magazine/do/mpub_15_303  При наличии двух глаголов (спрягаемого и инфинитива) оба входят в состав глагольного сказуемого, если действия относятся к одному лицу – субъекту действия: Чины людьми даются, а люди могут обмануться. (Грибоедов) Если же действия совершают разные лица, тогда инфинитив не является частью составного глагольного сказуемого, а выступает в роли второстепенного члена: Брат просил Павку приехать во что бы то ни стало.